# Keeping handsets in sync with a database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

On the system I am developing, we have a PostgreSQL database that contains set up data which when updated must be transfered to handsets when and while those handsets are "docked".  While the handsets are docked, our "service software" can talk to them, but not while they are undocked (they are not wireless).

At the moment, the service software that the handsets talk to loads the set up data from the database on startup and caches it.  Thereafter it queries the latest timestamp of the setup data every 5 seconds and reloads parts of the set up if the timestamp queried is higher than the latest cached timestamp.

However, I find this method haphazard.  It may be possible to miss an update for instance if an update transaction takes longer than a second, or at least if the period between submitting the transaction and completion of the transaction takes it over a 1-second boundary (the now() function is resolved at the beginning of the transaction by PostgreSQL).  The only way I can think of round that is to do a table level lock before querying the latest timestamp.  I'm not a fan of table locks but it is the only way I can think of to get round the problem.

Another problem with this approach is, I have to query for new data based on the update timetamp being >= the last latest timestamp, as opposed to just > the last latest timestamp.  Why?  Because a record may of been committed within the same second, just after my query - so I'd miss the record.

Another approach I've thought of is, storing "last synchronised date-time" data in the database for each logical item of data that must be stored on the handsets.  I would do this on a per handset basis.  I can then periodically query for all data not currently synchronised on a particular handset, and then mark it as synchronised once the handset is up to date (I have worked out a mechanism for this to be failsafe which takes into account the data being updated during synchronisation).

My only problem with this approach is that it means the database is storing non-business centric data - as in it is storing data to make the system work.  I'm not convinced data about what handsets are in sync is "business" data.  To me it is more the responsibility of the handset service software / handset software to know how to keep itself up to date, though it is tempting as it describes perfectly what data is and is not on each handset and allows queries to only return the data needed.

The first approach however at least only uses data appropriate to the business - i.e. the timestamp of when the data was last changed.

The ideal way would be to use some kind of notification system, but unfortunately postgres only has a basic NOTIFY / EVENT system and that doesn't seem to work over ODBC (which I foolishly decided to use and do not have time to change just now).  If I was using Oracle I could use Streams..

Thoughts?

Note: The database is purely relational - I am not interested in any "object oriented" approaches to this problem or any framework based solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using PostgreSQL version at least 7.2, the `now` function returns values with microsecond precision rather that second precision; although the value is ultimately derived from the operating system and will be accurate only up to a few hundredths of a second.

The method that you describe appears to be safe against permanently missing any updates.  Just make sure that you reload data *every time* unless the timestamps prove that you have reloaded long enough after the last update.  Alternately, you could update a timestamp upon data update in a separate transaction; in that case, ever seeing such a timestamp is a proof that all updates had finished before the timestamp value.

> Another approach I've thought of is, storing "last synchronised
>   date-time" data in the database for each logical item of data that
>   must be stored on the handsets. I would do this on a per handset
>   basis. I can then periodically query for all data not currently
>   synchronised on a particular handset, and then mark it as synchronised
>   once the handset is up to date

I can not recommend this for the following reasons:

- As synchronization is a state of a handset and not a state of the data, this information should better be stored on the handset.
- The database should be scalable to many handsets and it ideally should not have to keep track of them.
- If a handset can change its identity, or be wiped or restored (reimaged) to a previous state without changing its identity, the database will get out of sync with the real state of the headset and no mechanism will ensure proper synchronization.

While `NOTIFY` is certainly preferable to constant polling, it is a problem orthogonal to where you store the synchronization progress.  You still need to have a polling capability to be able to deal with a freshly connected devide, and notifications would be just a bandwidth/latency optimization.